# La différence entre "Je peux t'en prêter 5$" et "Je peux te prêter 5$"

Tags: grammaire, usage, pronoms, unités

Je ne comprends pas la différence entre  "Je peux t'en prêter 5$" et "Je peux te prêter 5$".
Pour moi, c'est normal pour dire "Je peux te prêter 5$", mais il y a beaucoup de résultats sur Google avec "en". Je suis anglophone.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

"Je peux t'en prêter **5$**" n'est pas correct, mais "je peux t'en prêter **5**" l'est, et implique que l'unité a été évoquée avant. Par exemple : "Peux-tu me prêter **10$** ? — Non, mais je peux t'en prêter **5**."

"Je peux te prêter 5$" quant à lui est correct, et n'impose pas de parler de l'unité avant. Par exemple : "Peux tu me prêter **de l'argent** ? - Oui, je peux te prêter **5$**."

Comment: Formidable, j'ai compri. Les résultats sur Google sont d'accord avec toi. L'unite n'est pas indiquée.

Comment: Si je veux remplacer une quantité dont on a parlé avant, peux-je dire "Je peux t'en prêter"?

Comment: Pour remplacer une quantité, on va utiliser "les". Exemple : "Tu peux me prêter 5$ ?" => Oui je peux te LES prêter.

Aussi, "peux-je" n'existe pas, c'est "puis-je"

Comment: @seek tu peux dire par exemple : "j'ai de l'argent et **je peux t'en prêter**" sans avoir besoin de parler de quantité ni d'unité, mais la réponse n'est pas très précise, et sera sûrement suivie de "Combien tu peux m'en prêter ?" ou bien de la même phrase qu'au départ : "Tu peux me prêter 5$ ?"

Comment: @xNeyte Dans ta phrase "Tu peux me prêter **5$** ?" il y a à la fois la quantité et l'unité. Cependant, la réponse "Oui je peux te **les** prêter" est juste mais oblige à parler de la quantité et de l'unité en amont.

Comment: @MorganFR Pour "Tu peux me prêter 5$?" peut-on repondre "Oui je peux t'en prêter"?

Comment: @seek Non, on peut dire "Oui, je peux", "Oui, je peux te les prêter" mais pas "Oui je peux t'en prêter".

Comment: L'explication est très bonne. :)

Answer (score 0):

> Je peux t'en prêter 5$

N'est pas du bon français. C'est probablement un abus de langage lié à une mauvaise prononciation.

Effectivement, la bonne solution est :

> Je peux te prêter 5$

Comment: Merci. Si je veux remplacer une quantité dont on a parlé avant, peux-je dire "Je peux t'en prêter"?

Comment: @MorganFR à donné une réponse plus complète. Comme il le dit, on aura tendance à spécifier le nombre, dans ce cas, ou une quantité.

Answer (score 0):

Les autres personnes ayant répondu à la question ont raison sur "je peux te prêter cinq dollars", mais l'autre tournure, bien que son sens ne soit pas le même, est tout à fait correcte. On l'utilisera pour quantifier le pronom "en", comme on pourrait dire :
 « — Tu as acheté de la farine ?
— Oui j'en pris trois kilogrammes. »